# Branching processes extinction (homework)

Tags: stochastic-processes

This is my stochastic process course homework. I can solve (a)(b), which are easy to prove. But I have no idea about (c). Could you give me some idea? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $P(\text{extinction}\mid X_n\ne0)=P(\text{extinction}; X_n\ne0)/P(X_n\ne0)$
- $P(X_n\ne0)\geqslant P(\text{survival})=1-P(\text{extinction})$
- $P(\text{extinction}; X_n\ne0)=P(\text{extinction})-P(X_n=0)$

This yields (if I am not mistaken and to help you check your solution to come) the upper bound
$$
P(\text{extinction}\mid X_n\ne0)\leqslant\frac{a}{1-a}\rho^n$$